# ASP.NET/Timer/Table + Image = No Tick/update

Tags: asp.net, timer, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I've got a page which retrieves character information from a remote service and then displays the information in a table which is inside an UpdatePanel.  The table refreshes perfectly fine if all I do is add tablerows, tablecells, and text to the table.  However, if I try to add images, either via the img tag or with the Image class, the table updates once and then refuses to update any more.

I've went through a handful of Google searches and read through the first couple pages worth of results on each search, as well as checking stackoverflow, and there are not any results that match my specific problem.  I can do without the images, but ideally, I'd like to add them in, as I wanted to use them to visually represent status effects currently affecting each game character.  The code is below.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scMain" runat="server" />
<asp:Timer ID="tmrRefresh" runat="server" Interval="5000" Enabled="true" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="udPanel" runat="server">
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tmrRefresh" EventName="Tick" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Table id="tblCharacters" runat="server">
        <asp:TableHeaderRow>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Focus</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Character</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Location</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Ping</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        </asp:TableHeaderRow>
    </asp:Table><br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblNote" runat="server" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Codebehind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Master.IsLoggedIn Then
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
    Else
        FillCharacterTable()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub FillCharacterTable()
    Dim Foci() As Byte = {0, 4, 10, 19, 24}
    Dim Names() As String = {"Unknown", "Gatekeeper", "Dreamseer", "Soulmaster", "Fatesender"}
    Dim HaloColors() As Byte = {0, 4, 15, 7, 18}

    Dim c As New CharacterInfoClient ' Remote service

    Dim Characters() As String = c.GetCharacterInformation

    For Each s As String In Characters
        Dim args() As String = s.Split("|")
        Dim tr As New TableRow
        ' add focus elemen icon
        Dim focus As Byte = Foci(args(2))

        ' option 1 - causes timer to stop updating
        tr.Cells.Add(New TableCell With {.Text = String.Format("<img src=""http://mydomainremoved.net/images/game/image.gif?s=7&v=3&c1={0}&c2={0}&st=50"">", focus))})

        ' Option 2, same thing
        Dim tc As New TableCell
        tc.Controls.Add(New Image With {.ImageUrl = String.Format("http://mydomainremoved.net/images/game/image.gif?s=7&v=3&c1={0}&c2={0}&st=50", focus)})

        tr.Cells.Add(tc)

        tr.Cells.Add(New TableCell With {.Text = "<a href=""character.aspx?id=" & args(1) & """>" & args(0) & "</a>"})
        tr.Cells.Add(New TableCell With {.Text = args(4)})
        tr.Cells.Add(New TableCell With {.Text = args(7)})

        tblCharacters.Rows.Add(tr)
    Next

    lblNote.Text = Characters.Length & " characters -- " & Now.ToString

End Sub
```

Comment: what should be the size of the image?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be worth experimenting with a CSS class rather than an image tag?

```
td.gatekeeper
{
     background-image: url('http://mydomainremoved.net/images/game/image.gif?s=7&v=3&c1=10&c2=10&st=50');
}
td.dreamseer
{
   // etc.
}
```

Since you have a limited number of possible values in your `Foci` array (I'm just assuming they're tied to the character names), you could set up multiple classes that each point to a specific image url, and assign whichever is needed based on the arguments to the method.